# Adding values to 2D Array String value Swift2

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, swift2

Below I have a constant `dict` that is of NSMutableArray type that stores my data extracted from JSON. I've tested that I'm able to extract what I need when referring to variable `name`.

While I know that appending a normal array would be `myArrayValue.append("String")`, however I tried the same method with my 2D array it doesn't work.

I'm quite new to Swift2 programming, please do explain in detail. Thanks in advance!

```
let dict: NSMutableArray!=(try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)) as! NSMutableArray

var arrayObject : [AnyObject]
var arrayName : [[String]] = [[]]
var name : String

for var x=0; x<dict.count; x++ {
        arrayObject = dict[x].allValues
    for var y=0; y<5; y++ {
        name = arrayObject[y].description as String
        arrayName[x][y].append(name)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I won't fix your code myself, there's too much work, I'm just telling you what is needed:

- You don't want to use Foundation's objects anymore if you don't actually need them, use Swift arrays.
- Don't call "dict" something that is an array.
- Don't force unwrap your values... use safe unwrapping with techniques like `if let`.
- Don't force with `try!`, use Do-Catch and Try instead, and handle errors.
- Don't use `MutableContainers` if you don't need this feature. Use an empty array instead for passing no options.
- Don't wrap in parenthesis things that don't need to be wrapped in parenthesis.
- Don't use manually indexed loops when you can use Swift paradigms like `for item in array { print(item) }`.
- `arrayName[x][y]` can't work if `arrayName[x]` is nil.

Once you've done these fixes and improvements, your current problem will disappear because your code will be easier to follow and maintain.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I'm very new to Swift, and will try my best to interpret what you meant.

Comment: You're welcome. That's a very good idea to try and improve your knowledge by yourself, best way to learn! On the other hand, don't hesitate to ask new questions if you're stuck somewhere - we'll be glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

Your post is hard reading, you didn't explain well your problem and I suppose it should be downvoted. Update your issue, if my answer is not correct, hope, it helps:

```
let JSONDict: [[String: AnyObject]] = [["name" : "value1"], ["name" : "value2"]];
var arrayName = [String]()
for dict in JSONDict {
    if let value = dict["name"] as? String {
       arrayName.append(value)
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry that my post is hard to read. Basically, I just need to store Strings into my 2 dimensional array.

`arrayName[0][0] = "String Value"` fails to execute.

Side track, because I have a data of 3000+ rows by 7 columns, with increasing rows over time due to more data. Would 2 dimensional array be the way to manage my data?